# Count based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, conditional-statements

Does anyone know how can I do a count in SQL Server based on condition.

Example:

How can I do a column count for records with name 'system', and total CaseID records in the table?

Customer table

```
UserID     CaseID     Name
1          100        alan
1          101        alan
1          102        amy
1          103        system
1          104        ken
1          105        ken
1          106        system
```

The result will display like below:

```
UserID    TotalCaseID    TotalRecordsWithSystem
1         7              2
```

Comment: Why should you not use `WHERE name = 'system'`?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use SUM/CASE...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),  --total
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'system' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --conditional
FROM
    myTable
```

Comment: Oh the old good SUM CASE... Always so helpful, always so easy to forget about. Thank you!

Comment: `ELSE 0 END` doesn't work for me. I have to use `ELSE null END` as per @kage 's answer

Comment: @SebastianJ. probably because you used `COUNT()` on the `CASE WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END` construction. If you use `SUM()` as shown it will work just fine.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE name='system'` works too, no need for `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 17):

I think he wanted user id in the results

```
SELECT 
    userid,
    COUNT(*) as TotalcaseID, --total 
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'system' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalRecordsWithSystem  
FROM 
    myTable 
group by userid
```

Comment: At that, example output shows `TotalCaseID`, too.

Answer (score 9):

```
select
userid,
count('x') as TotalCaseID,
count(case when name = 'system' then 'x' else null end) as TotalRecordsWithSystem
from CustomerTable
group by userid
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're on SQL Server 2012+, then you can use `SUM/IIF`

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(IIF(Name = 'system', 1, 0)) AS SystemTotal
FROM
    CustomerTable
```