# more efficient way to write this query? to get count of records based on different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say in my **Shop** table I have columns:

```
Store, Region, Name, EmployeeType
```

And there are s Employee Types:

```
Regular, Contractor
```

I want to get a count of how many regular and contractor type employees are in each Store, Region combination.

Currently I have this query code:

```
select distinct Store, Region, RegularCount, ContractorCount
from shop s
left join (
    select Store, Region, count(*) as RegularCount
    from shop 
    where employeetype like 'regular'
) rc
on rc.store = s.store and rc.region = s.region
left join (
    select Store, Region, count(*) as ContractorCount
    from shop 
    where employeetype like 'conctractor'
) cc
on cc.store = s.store and cc.region = s.region
```

I want to know if there's a more efficient way to do this?
Because if there are more employee types, then i'll have to increase number of my subqueries, which is not very scalable.

I looked into using **count(*) over** but I dont think that's the way to go in this case?

**note**:
the suggested duplication post does not solve my "scalability" problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count based on condition in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455201/count-based-on-condition-in-sql-server)

Comment: if you want a scalable way I think you could actually use the analytical function (count(*) over (partiotion by...) in a subquery and then group its result and concatenate it. However, you wouldn't get separate columns for each "employeetype", but instead everything would be in one column as for example: "conctractor: 5; regular: 12" as so on

Comment: Your subqueries are missing `group by`s.  That is an oversight if the code actually works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ooops i forgot to put that in. but i do have group by clause in my actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select Store, Region,
       sum(case when employeetype like 'regular' then 1 else 0 end) as RegularCount,
       sum(case when employeetype like 'contractor' then 1 else 0 end) as ContractorCount
from shop 
group by Store, Region;
```

If you have an unknown number of `employeetype` values, then put one on each row:

```
select Store, Region, employeetype, COUNT(*)
from shop 
group by Store, Region, employeetype;
```

Comment: thank you so much! this definitely helped but im looking for a more scalable way, as in they'll automatically grab the employeetype and count?

Answer (score 0):

See if this fits your needs, it doesn't have multiple columns for output however like the other answers. I find it's easier to dynamically add rows of data vs columns with SQL output. Otherwise dynamic SQL would probably be necessary to add columns dynamically.

```
select 
  Store, 
  Region,
  employeetype,
  COUNT(employeetype) AS CountOfEmplType
from shop 
group by Store, Region, employeetype;
```

This will be [less](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-performance-of-the-t-sql-window-functions/) efficient than an aggregate query but also could work.

```
Select 
    DISTINCT
    Store,
    Region,
    EmployeeType,
    Count(*) over (partition by EmployeeType)
from shop
```

Comment: Window functions are very much not needed for this.  The OP is not "spot on".

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, it definitely helped!

Answer (score 0):

I would add another column. I think this will get you what you want:

`Select region,
           Store,
          Employeetype,
          Count(*) as tot_emp
From shop
Group by region,
          store,
          employeetype`