# Counts for specific properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which I know is incorrect syntax

```
SELECT Vender as Carrier,
 count(IsPup WHERE IsPup = 1) as PU, 
 count(IsFull WHERE IsFull = 1) as FU,
 count(*) as NUM, count(IsPup)/2 + Count(IsFull) as FTE
 FROM Trailers WHERE Completed = 0 group by Vender order by NUM;
```

In particular the `count(IsPup WHERE IsPup = 1)` is wrong, I've searched various phrases like "How to count multiple properties of rows in SQL" etc.
and tried other manipulations of the same query like `count(IsPup) as PU, count(IsFull) as FU`

I had the syntactically correct query

```
SELECT Vender as Carrier, 
count(IsPup) as PU,
count(IsFull) as FU, 
count(*) as NUM, 
count(IsPup)/2 + Count(IsFull) as FTE 
FROM Trailers WHERE Completed = 0 group by Vender order by NUM
```

Which runs but PU, FU, and NUM are always being the same value...

I'm trying to get a table like below

```
| Carrier   | PU        | FU  |  NUM | FTE |
--------------------------------------------
| Vender1   | 2         |  1  |   3  | 2   |
| Vender2   | 0         |  4  |   4  | 4   |
| TOTAL     | 2         |  5  |   7  | 6   |
```

The trailers table has IsPup and IsFull as the `BIT` type so they are true or false (0 or 1)
I thought this query would be simple and feel like I am missing something obvious

How do I get the counts of each separate property and the total count?
The duplicate question marked doesn't match the format with the total on the bottom.

Comment: What are the potential values of `IsPup` and `IsFull`? It looks like you could use a SUM(CASE) statement. and then use `With Rollup` after your `Group By`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count based on condition in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455201/count-based-on-condition-in-sql-server)

Comment: What you wanted to google was "sql server several counts based on condition"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    VENDER
,   SUM(CAST(IsPUP AS INT)) AS PU
,   SUM(CAST(IsFull AS INT)) AS FU
,   COUNT(*) AS NUM
,   SUM(CAST(IsPUP AS INT)) * .5 + SUM(CAST(IsFull AS INT))
FROM Trailers
WHERE COMPLETED = 0
GROUP BY VENDER
WITH ROLLUP
```