# SQL - counts for two days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GuidId] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [Operation] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Status] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [UserId] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL)
```

Am trying to get query like

```
SELECT TOP 25 UserId, TableName, Operation, COUNT(1) Records 
FROM dbo.Log  
WHERE CreatedDate > GETDATE() - 1 
    AND Status='failed' 
GROUP BY UserId, TableName,Operation
```

I need to add another column to have output of count that has GetDate() - 7 criteria too in the same select. 
Share some thoughts

Comment: Why does it need to be within the same result set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count based on condition in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455201/count-based-on-condition-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 25
    UserId
    , TableName
    , Operation
    , SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate > GETDATE() - 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Records1Day
    , COUNT(1) Records7Days
FROM dbo.Log
WHERE
    CreatedDate > GETDATE() - 7
    AND Status='failed'
GROUP BY
    UserId
    , TableName
    , Operation
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent UserID fails that had a MAX(CreatedDate) > yesterday.  The subquery dT, below does this using MAX(CreatedDate) for the user ID, and HAVING to filter.  This is Ordered in descending faildate order.  I subqueried because you added the condition that you want to know the date for 7 days prior to this, and the receiving query does this...  using DATEADD to subtract 7 days from the [Most Recent UserID Failure] date.

```
SELECT dT.UserId
      ,dT.[Most Recent UserID Failure]
      ,DATEADD(DAY, -7, dT.[Most Recent UserID Failure]) AS [7 Days ago]
      ,(SELECT COUNT (*) 
          FROM #Log 
         WHERE UserId = dT.UserID
           AND CreatedDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(dT.[Most Recent UserID Failure] as date))
           AND CreatedDate <= dT.[Most Recent UserID Failure]
           AND Status = 'failed'
       ) AS [Num Fails]
  FROM (        
        SELECT TOP 25
               UserID
              ,MAX(CreatedDate) AS [Most Recent UserID Failure]
          FROM Log
         WHERE Status = 'failed'   
        GROUP BY UserID
        HAVING MAX(CreatedDate) > GETDATE() - 1
        ORDER BY [Most Recent UserID Failure] DESC
      ) AS dT
```